# Сканирование каталога с фото Python

Tags: python, файлы, функции

Задача состёгнутом, чтобы разработать набор классов для рекурсивного сканирования каталога, его подкаталогов и включенных файлов. Размеры, размеры вскорости сжатия должны быть вычислены и сохранены(в
памяти)для всех каталогов и файлов изображений. Для каталогов должна быть возможность вычислить сумму размеров файлов в каталоге и его в подкаталогах, средние размеры изображения и среднюю степень сжатия.
Иерархия каталогов и файлов должна быть сопоставлена с подходящей объектной моделью, для которой легко добавить дополнительные функциональные возможности.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Начните с метода os.listdir(), а дальше смотрите методы, которые дадут информацию о файлах итд

Comment: И в чём у вас сложность, собственно? Выглядит не сложной, но объёмной задачей, которую просто нужно декомпозировать и постепенно сделать.